# Why this data is rendering multiple time in MERN web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to fetch data into a table, but when I fetch the data from the API, The data is rendering multiple times. In the database, I have only 6 data but in the table, each column of data is rendering 6 times, and a total of 36 columns rendering for 6 data.

Have a look at how the data is rendering: [image]

Here is the *"application.js"* where I rendering the data:

```
const PendingApplication = (props) => {
    const [kamform, setKamforms] = useState([]);
    const [filterOpen, setFilterOpen] = useState(false);
    const [searchOptions, setSearchOptions] = useState({
        query: '',
    });

    const setPopup = useContext(SetPopupContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    const getData = () => {
        let searchParams = [];
        if (searchOptions.query !== '') {
            searchParams = [...searchParams, `q=${searchOptions.query}`];
        }

        const queryString = searchParams.join('&');
        console.log(queryString);
        let address = apiList.kamform;
        if (queryString !== '') {
            address = `${address}?${queryString}`;
        }

        axios
            .get(address, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                },
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setKamforms(
                    response.data.filter((obj) => {
                        const kcpnid = obj.kcpnid;
                        return kcpnid;
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.response.data);
                setPopup({
                    open: true,
                    severity: 'error',
                    message: 'Error',
                });
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Ticket No</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Category</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Sub Category</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Request Time & Date</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Company Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Action</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {kamform.map((item, index) => (
                        <TableRow key={index}>
                            <TableCell>{item.ticketno}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.approvecategory}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.subcategory}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.date}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.companyname}</TableCell>

                            <TableCell>
                                <Button>Detail</Button>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And here is the *"API"* for get the data from database:

```
router.get('/kam', jwtAuth, (req, res) => {
    let user = req.user;

    let findParams = {};
    let sortParams = {};
    if (user.type === 'kcp' && req.query.myjobs) {
        findParams = {
            ...findParams,
            userId: user._id,
        };
    }

    if (req.query.q) {
        findParams = {
            ...findParams,
            title: {
                $regex: new RegExp(req.query.q, 'i'),
            },
        };
    }

    console.log(findParams);
    console.log(sortParams);
    let arr = [
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'kamforms',
                localField: 'userId',
                foreignField: 'userId',
                as: 'kam',
            },
        },
        { $unwind: '$kam' },
        { $match: findParams },
    ];

    if (Object.keys(sortParams).length > 0) {
        arr = [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'kams',
                    localField: 'userId',
                    foreignField: 'userId',
                    as: 'kam',
                },
            },
            { $unwind: '$kam' },
            { $match: findParams },
            {
                $sort: sortParams,
            },
        ];
    }

    console.log(arr);

    kamForm
        .aggregate(arr)
        .then((posts) => {
            if (posts == null) {
                res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'No application found',
                });
                return;
            }
            res.json(posts);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(400).json(err);
        });
});
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: What are you unwinding there? How does your data looks like?

Comment: You are rendering 36 rows*.
The network response has indeed 36 items, which implies your frontend is doing the proper mapping. The problem must be on your database to network response mappers, where instead of 6 items, 36 are returned.

Comment: try kamform.forEach()